# reachabilityWithHostName timeout

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios4, network-programming, reachability

I'm implementing the Reachability class to check connection status as follows:

```
Reachabilitty *reachability = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:@"apple.com"];
Network status = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];

if(status == NotReachable){
    ...
}else if(status == ReachableViaWifi){
    ...
}else if(status == ReachableViaWWNA){
    ...
}
```

It's possible to set a timeOut when I'm calling to apple.com to check connection?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use timer or thread for this.

Answer (score -1):

This is from Apple and it's really good.

```
#import <sys/socket.h>
#import <netinet/in.h>
#import <netinet6/in6.h>
#import <arpa/inet.h>
#import <ifaddrs.h>
#import <netdb.h>

#import <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>

#import "Reachability.h"

#define kShouldPrintReachabilityFlags 1

static void PrintReachabilityFlags(SCNetworkReachabilityFlags    flags, const char* comment)
{
#if kShouldPrintReachabilityFlags

    NSLog(@"Reachability Flag Status: %c%c %c%c%c%c%c%c%c %s\n",
            (flags & kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsIsWWAN)               ? 'W' : '-',
            (flags & kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsReachable)            ? 'R' : '-',

            (flags & kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsTransientConnection)  ? 't' : '-',
            (flags & kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsConnectionRequired)   ? 'c' : '-',
            (flags & kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsConnectionOnTraffic)  ? 'C' : '-',
            (flags & kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsInterventionRequired) ? 'i' : '-',
            (flags & kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsConnectionOnDemand)   ? 'D' : '-',
            (flags & kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsIsLocalAddress)       ? 'l' : '-',
            (flags & kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsIsDirect)             ? 'd' : '-',
            comment
            );
#endif
}


@implementation Reachability
static void ReachabilityCallback(SCNetworkReachabilityRef target, SCNetworkReachabilityFlags flags, void* info)
{
    #pragma unused (target, flags)
    NSCAssert(info != NULL, @"info was NULL in ReachabilityCallback");
    NSCAssert([(NSObject*) info isKindOfClass: [Reachability class]], @"info was wrong class in ReachabilityCallback");

    //We're on the main RunLoop, so an NSAutoreleasePool is not necessary, but is added defensively
    // in case someon uses the Reachablity object in a different thread.
    NSAutoreleasePool* myPool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    Reachability* noteObject = (Reachability*) info;
    // Post a notification to notify the client that the network reachability changed.
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName: kReachabilityChangedNotification object: noteObject];

    [myPool release];
}

- (BOOL) startNotifier
{
    BOOL retVal = NO;
    SCNetworkReachabilityContext    context = {0, self, NULL, NULL, NULL};
    if(SCNetworkReachabilitySetCallback(reachabilityRef, ReachabilityCallback, &context))
    {
        if(SCNetworkReachabilityScheduleWithRunLoop(reachabilityRef, CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), kCFRunLoopDefaultMode))
        {
            retVal = YES;
        }
    }
    return retVal;
}

- (void) stopNotifier
{
    if(reachabilityRef!= NULL)
    {
        SCNetworkReachabilityUnscheduleFromRunLoop(reachabilityRef, CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), kCFRunLoopDefaultMode);
    }
}

- (void) dealloc
{
    [self stopNotifier];
    if(reachabilityRef!= NULL)
    {
        CFRelease(reachabilityRef);
    }
    [super dealloc];
}

+ (Reachability*) reachabilityWithHostName: (NSString*) hostName;
{
    Reachability* retVal = NULL;
    SCNetworkReachabilityRef reachability = SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName(NULL, [hostName UTF8String]);
    if(reachability!= NULL)
    {
        retVal= [[[self alloc] init] autorelease];
        if(retVal!= NULL)
        {
            retVal->reachabilityRef = reachability;
            retVal->localWiFiRef = NO;
        }
    }
    return retVal;
}

+ (Reachability*) reachabilityWithAddress: (const struct sockaddr_in*) hostAddress;
{
    SCNetworkReachabilityRef reachability = SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(kCFAllocatorDefault, (const struct sockaddr*)hostAddress);
    Reachability* retVal = NULL;
    if(reachability!= NULL)
    {
        retVal= [[[self alloc] init] autorelease];
        if(retVal!= NULL)
        {
            retVal->reachabilityRef = reachability;
            retVal->localWiFiRef = NO;
        }
    }
    return retVal;
}

+ (Reachability*) reachabilityForInternetConnection;
{
    struct sockaddr_in zeroAddress;
    bzero(&zeroAddress, sizeof(zeroAddress));
    zeroAddress.sin_len = sizeof(zeroAddress);
    zeroAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
    return [self reachabilityWithAddress: &zeroAddress];
}

+ (Reachability*) reachabilityForLocalWiFi;
{
    struct sockaddr_in localWifiAddress;
    bzero(&localWifiAddress, sizeof(localWifiAddress));
    localWifiAddress.sin_len = sizeof(localWifiAddress);
    localWifiAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
    // IN_LINKLOCALNETNUM is defined in <netinet/in.h> as 169.254.0.0
    localWifiAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(IN_LINKLOCALNETNUM);
    Reachability* retVal = [self reachabilityWithAddress: &localWifiAddress];
    if(retVal!= NULL)
    {
        retVal->localWiFiRef = YES;
    }
    return retVal;
}

#pragma mark Network Flag Handling

- (NetworkStatus) localWiFiStatusForFlags: (SCNetworkReachabilityFlags) flags
{
    PrintReachabilityFlags(flags, "localWiFiStatusForFlags");

    BOOL retVal = NotReachable;
    if((flags & kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsReachable) && (flags & kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsIsDirect))
    {
        retVal = ReachableViaWiFi;  
    }
    return retVal;
}

- (NetworkStatus) networkStatusForFlags: (SCNetworkReachabilityFlags) flags
{
    PrintReachabilityFlags(flags, "networkStatusForFlags");
    if ((flags & kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsReachable) == 0)
    {
        // if target host is not reachable
        return NotReachable;
    }

    BOOL retVal = NotReachable;

    if ((flags & kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsConnectionRequired) == 0)
    {
        // if target host is reachable and no connection is required
        //  then we'll assume (for now) that your on Wi-Fi
        retVal = ReachableViaWiFi;
    }


    if ((((flags & kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsConnectionOnDemand ) != 0) ||
        (flags & kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsConnectionOnTraffic) != 0))
    {
            // ... and the connection is on-demand (or on-traffic) if the
            //     calling application is using the CFSocketStream or higher APIs

            if ((flags & kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsInterventionRequired) == 0)
            {
                // ... and no [user] intervention is needed
                retVal = ReachableViaWiFi;
            }
        }

    if ((flags & kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsIsWWAN) == kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsIsWWAN)
    {
        // ... but WWAN connections are OK if the calling application
        //     is using the CFNetwork (CFSocketStream?) APIs.
        retVal = ReachableViaWWAN;
    }
    return retVal;
}

- (BOOL) connectionRequired;
{
    NSAssert(reachabilityRef != NULL, @"connectionRequired called with NULL reachabilityRef");
    SCNetworkReachabilityFlags flags;
    if (SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(reachabilityRef, &flags))
    {
        return (flags & kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsConnectionRequired);
    }
    return NO;
}

- (NetworkStatus) currentReachabilityStatus
{
    NSAssert(reachabilityRef != NULL, @"currentNetworkStatus called with NULL reachabilityRef");
    NetworkStatus retVal = NotReachable;
    SCNetworkReachabilityFlags flags;
    if (SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(reachabilityRef, &flags))
    {
        if(localWiFiRef)
        {
            retVal = [self localWiFiStatusForFlags: flags];
        }
        else
        {
            retVal = [self networkStatusForFlags: flags];
        }
    }
    return retVal;
}
@end
```

------------ M File

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <SystemConfiguration/SystemConfiguration.h>

typedef enum {
    NotReachable = 0,
    ReachableViaWiFi,
    ReachableViaWWAN
} NetworkStatus;
#define kReachabilityChangedNotification @"kNetworkReachabilityChangedNotification"

@interface Reachability: NSObject
{
    BOOL localWiFiRef;
    SCNetworkReachabilityRef reachabilityRef;
}

//reachabilityWithHostName- Use to check the reachability of a particular host name. 
+ (Reachability*) reachabilityWithHostName: (NSString*) hostName;

//reachabilityWithAddress- Use to check the reachability of a particular IP address. 
+ (Reachability*) reachabilityWithAddress: (const struct sockaddr_in*) hostAddress;

//reachabilityForInternetConnection- checks whether the default route is available.  
//  Should be used by applications that do not connect to a particular host
+ (Reachability*) reachabilityForInternetConnection;

//reachabilityForLocalWiFi- checks whether a local wifi connection is available.
+ (Reachability*) reachabilityForLocalWiFi;

//Start listening for reachability notifications on the current run loop
- (BOOL) startNotifier;
- (void) stopNotifier;

- (NetworkStatus) currentReachabilityStatus;
//WWAN may be available, but not active until a connection has been established.
//WiFi may require a connection for VPN on Demand.
- (BOOL) connectionRequired;
@end
```

Use startNotifierand stopNotifier to monitor WiFi status

Implementation

Add a UILabel and UIButton to a view

Add the following to your.h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Reachability.h"

@interface ReachabilityExampleViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UIButton *checkButton;
    IBOutlet UILabel *reachabilityLabel;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *checkButton;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *reachabilityLabel;

- (IBAction)checkForReachability;

@end
```

Here is your .M file

```
#import "ReachabilityExampleViewController.h"

@implementation ReachabilityExampleViewController
@synthesize checkButton, reachabilityLabel;

-(BOOL)reachable {
    Reachability *r = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:@"google.com"];
    NetworkStatus internetStatus = [r currentReachabilityStatus];
    if(internetStatus == NotReachable) {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}

- (IBAction)checkForReachability {
    if ([self reachable]) {
        reachabilityLabel.text = @"Reachable";
    }
    else {
        reachabilityLabel.text = @"Not Reachable";
    }
}
```

Comment: so... where is the parameter for the time out? can you post an example of the implementation? thanks

Comment: Look at the startNotifier Method. It does SCNetworkReachabilitySetCallback(reachabilityRef, ReachabilityCallback, &context)) and if you look up ReachabilityCallback method, you'll see it goes to the Notification Center so it runs periodically in the background. This website should help http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/SystemConfiguration/Reference/SCNetworkReachabilityRef/Reference/reference.html

Comment: there is nothing connected with timeout for determining reachability of a host

Comment: @peetonn, as to reachability timeout set, have you got the solution? Thanks